# Validating document classification procedure using scikit-learn and NLTK (python 3.4) yielding awkward MDS stress

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, nltk, text-mining

This is my first post on SO so I hope I'm not committing any posting crimes just yet ;-). This is verbose because part of what I am trying to do is to validate my process and ensure I understand how this is done without screwing up majorly. I will sum up my questions here:

1. How can I have a stress value in the 50's from an MDS? I thought it should be between 0 and 1.
2. Running a clustering function on coordinates obtained through MDS is a big no-no? I ask because my results do not change significantly doing so but it could just be because of my data
3. I want to validate my `k` value for the number of clusters using an "elbow" method. How can I compute this knowing that I rely on `linkage()` and `fcluster()` to plot a number of clusters against an error value? Any help on methods or calls to access that data or the data I need to compute it would be greatly appreciated.

I am working on a document classification scheme using python 3.4 for a pet projet I have where I want to feed a corpus of several thousand texts and classify them using hierarchical clustering. I also would like to use MDS to graphically represent the cluster structures (I will also use a dendrogram but want to give this a shot).

Anyway, first thing I want to do is validate my procedure to make sure I understand how this works. This is done using NLTK and scikit-learn. My objective is not to call one procedure in scikit-learn that would do everything. Rather, I want to compute my similarity matrix (using a procedure in NLTK for example) and then feed that into a clustering function, using the precomputed parameter in some of the methods I rely on.

So my steps are currently as follows:

1. Load corpus
2. Clean up corpus items: remove stop words and
   unwanted chars (numerical values and other text that is not relevant
   to my objective); use lemmatization (WordNet)
3. the end result is a matrix with n documents and m terms
4. Compute the similarity between documents: for each document, compute cosine
   similarity against the matrix of terms.

To do that, I use **TfidfVectorizer**

Note: I am a python newbie so I may not do things in a pythonic way. I apologize in advance...

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = tokenize, preprocessor = preprocess)
sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(term_dict.values())
```

The tokenizer and preprocessor methods are dummy methods I had to add so that it would not try and tokenize etc. my dictionary which was previously built.

The cosine similarity matrix is built using:

```
i = 0
return_matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(document_terms_list))] for x in range(len(document_terms_list))]
for index in enumerate(document_terms_list):
    if (i < len(document_terms_list)):
        similarity = cosine_similarity(sparse_matrix[i:i+1], sparse_matrix)
        M = coo_matrix(similarity)
        for k, j, v in zip(M.row, M.col, M.data):
            return_matrix[i][j] = v
    i += 1
```

So for 100 documents, `return_matrix` is basically 100 x 100 with each cell having a similarity between Doc_x and Doc_y.

5. My next step is to perform the clustering (I want to use `complete` using scipy's `hierarchical clustering`).
6. To reduce dimensionality and be able to visualize results, I first perform an MDS on the data:

   ```
   mds = manifold.MDS(n_components = 2, dissimilarity = "precomputed", verbose = 1)
   results = mds.fit(return_matrix)
   coordinates = results.embedding_
   ```

My problem arises here: calling `mds.stress_` reports a value of about 53. I was under the understanding that my stress value should be somewhere between 0 and 1. Ahem, needless to say that I am speechless with this... This would be my first question. When I print the similarity matrix etc. everything looks relatively good...

7. To build the clusters, I am currently passing in `coordinates` to the `linkage()` and `fcluster()` functions, i.e. I am passing in the MDS'ed version of my similarity matrix. Now, I wonder if this could be an issue although the results look ok when I look at the clusters assigned to my data. But conceptually, I am not sure this makes sense.
8. In trying to determine an ideal number of clusters, I want to use an "elbow" method, plotting the variance explained against the number of clusters to have an "ideal" cutoff. I am not sure I see this anywhere in the scikit-learn docs and tutorials. I see places where people do it in R etc. but when I use hierarchical clustering, how can I achieve this? I just don't know where to get the data from the API and what data I am looking for exactly.

Many thanks in advance. I apologize for the length of this post but I figured giving out some context might help.

Cheers,

Greg

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the stress values. Did you find any solution/explanation? Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, nope unfortunately I did not manage to get it to work properly. I therefore did not use MDS at all.